# How to create account in Zenodo from command line?

Tags: python, shell, zenodo

I am using Zenodo for sharing the dataset for open science.

I am uploading dataset using commands from  https://github.com/jhpoelen/zenodo-upload to automate the task i.e.

`./zenodo_upload.sh [deposition id] [filename]`

However, I want to automate the whole flow i.e.:

- create zenodo account
- upload to zenodo

To be more concrete, run a sh or python script from a ubuntu machine:

- from a ubuntu machine create an account in Zenodo using the command line
- Upload the dataset

Is it possible to do this?

I would be interested to listen about whether there is an alternative to it or not?